# how to set Status Bar white ios 7.1?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

It´s very weird, In my app Im adding the

```
   "View controller-based status bar appearance" "boolean" "NO"
```

and in appdelegate the line:

```
[application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

The weird thing is that it actually shows correctly on any iphone, and ipad non-retina but it´s not showing on iPad retina, any idea???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a simulator bug, in real devices it works as expected.

setting in the info.plist

```
"View controller-based status bar appearance" "boolean" "NO"
```

and in applicationdidfinishlaunching:

```
 [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

Answer (score 1):

iOS 7 doesn't have a background behind the status bar, it's always transparent. There is no way to set the colour.

The light/dark content changes the colour of the text in the status bar. You are responsible as the app developer for putting a view behind the status bar with whatever colour you want, which could be white.

setting in the info.plist

```
"View controller-based status bar appearance" "boolean" "YES"
```

and in applicationdidfinishlaunching:

```
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

and add this method in every view controller .m file for App Delegate .m

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 doesn't have a background behind the status bar, it's always transparent. There is no way to set the colour.

The light/dark content changes the colour of the text in the status bar. You are responsible as the app developer for putting a view behind the status bar with whatever colour you want, which could be white.

Comment: Maybe you missunderstood the situation, In my last app, i wanted the status bar to show white letters, with the parameters i set it works perfectly, but for some reason it doesnt work on ipads with retina screen... I have a background image blackGray, but is like if being retina the status bar is not showwing